# Uncaught Error: [Parchment] Cannot insert block into block in Quill Editor

Tags: javascript, editor, quill

Please help me with this Question
I'm trying to integrate Quill Editor into AngularJs and I have the following error when I want to edit the table, does not allow edit in this version

document.getElementById(`editor-container`).getElementsByClassName("ql-blank")[0].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML
= $scope.translationData.Translations[i].Text;

does not make a error but the table does not show in this case

QuillInstance.container.firstChild.innerHTML = $scope.translationData.Translations[i].Text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.